# Заполнение инпута по нажатию на checkbox

Tags: typescript, angular

Имеется инпут, который можно заполнить с помощью поиска по элемента, либо по клику на чексбокс. При нажатии на чекбокс инпут должен заполняться дефолтным значением `valueText`

```js
 public foundedElement: Element[];
 public defaultValue: boolean;
 public valueText = "text";
 
 constructor(public elementFacade: ElementFacade) {}
 
 addField(value) {
    return currentElement.field = value;
 }

 searchElement(e): void {
    const {value} = e.target;
    if (value.length > 1) {
      this.elementFacade.getAll({name: value}).subscribe(el => this.foundedElement = el);
    }
  }
```

```html
     <input-container>
       <input #elementInput
              [mdAutocomplete]="autoElement"
              (input)="searchElement($event)"
              [ngModel]="currentElement ? currentElement.field : ''"
       />
       <md-autocomplete #autoElement="mdAutocomplete">
         <md-option
           *ngFor="let el of foundedElement"
           (onSelectionChange)="addField(el.name)">
           {{el.name}}
         </md-option>
       </md-autocomplete>
     </input-container>
      <md-checkbox  [checked]="defaultValue">Default</md-checkbox>
```

Comment: как-то непонятно, `searchElement` обрабатывает событие `input`, но вы хотите зассетить `value` инпута после выбора значения в `md-option`, не вижу просто связи между приведенным вами кодом, у вас есть метод `addField`, который обрабатывает событие `onSelectionChange`, вот в нем и сеттите `value` инпута

Comment: @overthesanity, можно пример, каким способом засетить в `addField`

Comment: я не знаю что такое `currentElement`, но в концепции angular ngmodel должен быть строчным, в вашем случае я вижу, что `currentElement` это объект и с этим тяжелее работать. В `addField` сеттите свойство `field` объектa `currentElement`